# Debian gnome-disks and mkfs can not format external hdd

Tags: debian, filesystems, hard-disk

I have an HDD bought a few years I have not touch since at least a year.
When connecting it to my laptop, the drive does not appear in the drive list in the file explorer.

I used `fdisk` to be sure it was connected and detected as `/dev/sdb`:

```
berhthun@debian:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for berhthun: 

Disque /dev/sda : 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 octets, 976773168 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 4096 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 4096 octets / 4096 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : dos
Identifiant de disque : 0x0b1495d8

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048  40011775  40009728  19,1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       40011776 976773167 936761392 446,7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       40013824  56307711  16293888   7,8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       56309760 976773119 920463360 438,9G 83 Linux

Disque /dev/sdb : 465,7 GiB, 500074283008 octets, 976707584 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : dos
Identifiant de disque : 0x00038e76

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 976707583 976705536 465,7G 83 Linux
```

After lookin on the Internet, I tried to use `mkfs` command to format it:

```
berhthun@debian:~$ sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for berhthun: 
Cluster size has been automatically set to 4096 bytes.
Initializing device with zeroes: 100% - Done.
Creating NTFS volume structures.
Error writing to /dev/sdb1: Erreur d'entrée/sortie
Error writing non-resident attribute value.
add_attr_sd failed: Erreur d'entrée/sortie
Couldn't create root directory: Erreur d'entrée/sortie
Failed to fsync device /dev/sdb1: Erreur d'entrée/sortie
Warning: Could not close /dev/sdb1: Erreur d'entrée/sortie
berhthun@debian:~$
```

I went to `gnome-disks`, the HDD is also detected. Partition format is unknown. It tells me the disk have a 500 Go space and that's it.

If I try to format the drive, it also tells me an error message:

```
Erreur lors du formatage du disque
Error creating file system: Command-line `parted --script "/dev/sdb" mktable msdos' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Error: Erreur d'entrée/sortie during read on /dev/sdb
Error: Erreur d'entrée/sortie during write on /dev/sdb
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

What can I do to make it work again ?
Thank you for your help.

*Update after Stephen Kitt comment:*
When using `dmesg` I find the following errors about the hdd:

```
[  748.613769] end_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 976707456
[  748.613777] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 122088432
[  756.133563] end_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 976707456
[  756.133571] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 122088432
[  868.845815] end_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 976707456
[  868.845821] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 122088176
[  945.172666] end_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 976707456
[  945.172674] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 122088176
[  975.727890] end_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 976707456
[  975.727898] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 122088432
```

And so on.

Comment: There probably isn't much you can do... `dmesg` will give more detailed error messages, there may be something useful there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated my question with dmesg errors shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the failing sectors are all at the end of the disk (976707456 and so on), you *could* use your disk with a shorter partition: delete `sdb1` and re-create a partition that's one or two megabytes shorter.

But I wouldn't trust such a disk: unless you use it for throwaway data, it's not worth the hassle and risk...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I won't use this hard drive. I also upvoted your answer but it will be only effective after getting 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a failling disk, however

try using `fdisk` and have 976707454 (or less) as last sector of /dev/sdb1

then format.

As Stephen Kitt pointed out, do not use critical data on it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I won't use this hard drive. I upvoted your answer but it will be only effective after getting 15 reputation.

Comment: I think @StephenKitt and I already have some reputation ...